API call error: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 8000ms (and no fallback has been configured)/Spring WebClient/Retry after timeout
When .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeout)) happens below message is printed
ERROR [parallel-6] com.www.xyz.bbb.restv2retry.RestV2ServiceImpl:888 - Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 80000ms in 'retryWhen' (and no fallback has been configured)
i get the message because timout has occured while calling api to some server and response did not came back,but i want to retry when timeout occurs so inside retryPolicy() method i used condition || throwable.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException to retry when timeout occurs but still not working.
Any idea how to retry after timeout happens ?
Below is the code
@Service
public class RestV2ServiceImpl implements RestV2Service {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestV2ServiceImpl.class);

    @Value("${apirest.server.requestTimeoutInSeconds}")
    private Long requestTimeout;

    @Value("${retryPolicy.maxAttempts}")
    private Integer restV2retryPolicyMaxAttempts;

    @Value("${retryPolicy.periodInMilliseconds}")
    private Long restV2initialInterval;

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Override
    public String updateRequestV2(String url, String requestJson, String versionSequence) {
        return webClient.patch()
                .uri(url)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json-patch+json")
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header("If-Match", versionSequence)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestJson))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(this::retryableStatuses, this::retryableStatusException)
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .retryWhen(retryPolicy())
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeout))
                .doOnError(throwable -> LOGGER.error(throwable.getMessage()))
                .block();
    }

   
    /**
     * Return the range of HTTP codes for which REST v2 requests should be retried.
     * @param status HttpStatus returned from a REST call
     * @return true if request should be retried
     */
    private boolean retryableStatuses(HttpStatus status) {
        return status.is5xxServerError();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an exception to be analyzed by the "retryWhen(...)" method to indicate
     * conditions for which a request should be retried.
     * @param response HTTP response from the latest REST request
     * @return
     */
    private Mono<? extends Throwable> retryableStatusException(ClientResponse response) {
        return response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(body ->
                new HttpServerErrorException(response.statusCode(), body));
    }

    /**
     * Defines the policy for retrying a REST request.
     * This policy retries on HttpServerErrorException created by the retryableStatusException
     * method (which defines retryable server side errors) and on WebClientRequestException which defines
     * client side errors prior to processing a request (e.g. certain request timeouts).
     * @return the policy
     */
    private Retry retryPolicy() {
        return Retry.backoff(restV2retryPolicyMaxAttempts, Duration.ofMillis(restV2initialInterval))
                    .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof HttpServerErrorException || throwable instanceof WebClientRequestException || || throwable.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException)
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow(((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> new RetryExhaustedException(retrySignal.failure().getMessage())));
    }
}


Need to retry even if timeout occurs

Order of operators matter. If you put the timeout after the retry, then it takes precedence over the retry mechanism. But if you put the retry after, then when the timeout occurs, the retry strategy will receive the timeout error and then will be able to retry it.

Issue solved.
There were 2 things that i changed.
Thanks @amanin  yes after changing order so first
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeout)) then 
    .retryWhen(retryPolicy())

it was going for retry.
throwable.getCause() instanceof TimeoutException - here i used
io.netty.handler.timeout.TimeoutException  but actually it was
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Worked After changing if condition to
throwable instanceof HttpServerErrorException
                                || throwable instanceof WebClientRequestException
                                || throwable instanceof TimeoutException;

